# Can't open .py with idle when moving file from Win to Ubuntu

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, python-idle

So I have a folder of python files on my desktop machine (win 10).

After copying the folder to my notebook (Ubuntu), I can't open them with IDLE (2.7). I can open the `.py` files created on the Ubuntu machine, it's the default text editor.

However when I go 'open with' on the newly copied files I can't see IDLE as optional. It's just not there.

Is there any workaround for this problem?

Comment: Ubuntu may not be able to recognize the file type right now and there might be several reason but you can change the default application for `.py` files.

Comment: Are you saying `open with` has `IDLE` as an option, but only for files created on Ubuntu?

Comment: To set the default application for a specific file type, locate a file of that type in the file manager, right-click it, and select Properties.

and then Click the `Open With tab` and select the application you want to use for that file type. Use the Set as default button to make the application the default application.

Comment: Yes, right click on the windows file and change it's default application setting as mentioned above.

Comment: @PeterWood Yes, that is the problem.

Comment: @Rahul You did not understand me. That's what exactly I can't do. It does not show IDLE as an option.

Comment: @MattSom Ok, I don't have a alternative solution then but it weird that it doesn't show in properties also because there you can make any application default for a particular file type.